# force https for certain pages in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

When I reach the url `http://www.example.com/payments/add/2`, it should automatically redirect to  `https://www.example.com/payments/add/2`.
*Note:* I have installed ssl on my server.

```
if($this->params['action']=='add' && $this->params['controller']=='payments') 
    { $this->redirect('https://' . env('SERVER_NAME') . $this->here); }
```

That code is not working. Please help

Comment: Your code references a controller called 'payments' but your urls are both trying to access a URL with controller 'apyments'. If this is not a typo, it could be the source of your problem.

Comment: sry its typo  mistake..!!  now i have edited.!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com (or any other subdomain)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#force https for certain pages    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(page1\.php|page2\.php|page3\.php|page4\.php)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```